# How should I make money?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was wondering mostly if I should be selling my magic items (the bad ones) to NPCs or if I should just keep on trying to sell them on the auciton house...

The limit of 10 simultaneous auctions hinders this "just put everything up for auction" mindset, so I was wondering what would be the "correct" way to earn money in this way.

Also how should I decide whether to salvage or sell? Should I (ideally) be selling solely if I need money and salvaging only if I need crafting materials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Equipment

- Gray / White (**Not worth to collect**)

Just sell them on the NPC.

- Blue (in high difficulties is not so worth to collect, better keep farming for rares)

You can create craft-items, but only if you want to craft something. Low level Blues have a good value in hardcore AH. Also blue amulets can be sold on AH if they have great statistics like 160 Dex.

But in general, the best thing to do is to sell them to an NPC.

- Rare / Legendary

AH is the best way for them, put low prices to sell fast, if you have lots (remember, only 10 items at a time).

---

A good way to farm gold is get quest rewards and farm Rare and champions mobs in high difficulties. So, get in inferno and start farming.

Comment: The time it takes to pick up and sell gray/white is not worth it, even if it is just a couple of seconds if that time was spend killing you would make more gold from random gold drops.

Comment: **Why down-voted it** ????? I didn't said that it was worth get the white/gray. I just told What to do if you get them. Editing to clarify this information.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't really any buyers for blue items on the auction house as far as I can tell.  I think you're better off just selling them to vendors if you can't use them.

Comment: Generally this is true, but I have bought a blue chest piece and a blue ring off the AH. Both had the exact combination of stats I needed to upgrade a piece that had worn out its welcome after 15+ levels.  Then again, I bought them because they were very cheap....

Comment: I've sold 3 blues so far :).

Comment: I already sold lots of blues in the AH.. but this is in Hardcore, where the amount of player and items is way lower.

Comment: High DPS blue weapons can sell for a hefty sum, particularly level 60 weapons with a reduced level requirement, but it's a niche market.

Answer (score 0):

imo, there is no need for mass ammounts of money until level 60. make sure you look over every blue or yellow item dropped, you'll be suprised how often you find a better piece of gear. most the money earnt should be from quests/monster drops. do not buy items off auction house while leveling. you'll spend 100k on a an item that you'll use for 5 levels.
money is not a problem.

Comment: It isn't necessarily true that you shouldn't buy items off the auction house.  You can get many items for less than 1000 gold, and it may help you level up faster and/or prevent deaths, and then you can sell it back when you're done.